# Looping A solver calculation by column

Tags: excel, loops, solver, vba

I'm just starting out in VBA and I'm trying to setup where a solver calculation is done for a range of multiple years, one after the other.  This is the simple code for 1 year.  How do I program it to tell it to do it for a range of columns, like from $I$96 to AP$96, one after the other?  Much appreciated.

```
    SolverOk SetCell:="$i$96", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$i$72", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$i$96", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$i$72", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve userFinish = False


End Sub
```

Comment: look into [`For ... Next Loops`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) using the a `For each cel in Range("I96:AP96")` construct where `cel` is the variable `Dim cel as Range`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute this fragment of code for a given range:

1. define your fragment of code as a function receiving "setcell" and "bychange" as range (if "bychange" never change, you can let it hard defined in the funtion and remove it from parameters)

   ```
   Public Sub Solver(byval cell as range, byval change as range)
       SolverOk SetCell:=cell, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=change, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
       SolverSolve userFinish = False
   End sub
   ```
2. Define the range you want to calculate and run this function for each cell in the range

   ```
   dim cell as range, rng as range
   set rng = Range("I96:AP96")    ' You should need to set range with Worksheet(<sheet>).Range()
   for each cell in rng
       call Solver(cell, Range("I72"))
   next
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and then generate the address string via cells function and Address method:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 9 To 42
    s1 = Cells(96, i).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True)
    s2 = Cells(72, i).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True)
    SolverOk SetCell:=s1, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=s2, Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=s1, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=s2, Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve userFinish = False
Next i
```